# SSRS Displaying detail data in a grid with two columns

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, datagrid, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a bit of a problem solving this SSRS problem. I was wondering if anyone has done this kind of thing before?

I'm struggling to figure out a way of getting detail data span over two columns. The reason I need the data like this is for printing address labels.

I was thinking of creating some sort of column grouping in the SQL query and then using that in a martix.

[image: Here's a pic of the layout of the data I need]

Any ideas? I'm stuck!

Comment: Id you're happy doing it in SSRS, you're probably looking at something like: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19064356/1228274

Comment: Make 2 columns in your SQl and select top 50% into one and the rest into the other.

Comment: @IanPreston This is really useful! I think I'm on the right track here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can generate a RowNr in your query and make a Rowgroup using this RowNr

```
select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by [address]) - (ROW_NUMBER() over (order by [address])+1)%2 RowNr, [address]
```

Then use first() and last() in the fields.